# Grouping and summing data R

Tags: r, statistics

I am working on a project for my statistical computing class that I am struggling with. I have a dataset that includes patient ID, visits(baseline, wk1, wk2, for each patient), and 10 variables that represent different drugs (the UDS variables shown in the snapshot below). Each "1" represents a positive drug screen. I have to clean up the dataset to just include patient ID and the number of positive drug screens. [Dataset snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6ZGs.jpg). I have to group all the patient visits per patient so that all the data is in one row, and then I have to sum all the values for each drug screen column per patient to get a final value which will be added as a new column.

I should mention that I am relatively new to R so I am trying my best to be proficient in the language.

I hope this makes sense and I apologize for any confusion. Thank you for all your help. I also attached a snap of what the clean dataset should look like. [Clean data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OGd4.jpg).

I have tried:

```
summary_urine_df <- Clean_urine_df %>%
group_by(PATDEID, VISIT) %>%
summarize(UDS005 = sum(UDS005), UDS006 = sum(UDS006), UDS007 = sum(UDS007), 
            UDS008 = sum(UDS008), UDS009 = sum(UDS009), UDS010 = sum(UDS010),
            UDS011 = sum(UDS011), UDS012 = sum(UDS012), UDS013 = sum(UDS013),
            UDS014 = sum(UDS014))
```

```
Cleaner_urine_df <- summary_urine_df %>% mutate(
  nPosScreen = UDS005 + UDS006 + UDS007 + UDS008
  + UDS009 + UDS010 + UDS011 + UDS012 + UDS013 + UDS014) %>%
  mutate(nPosScreens = as.numeric(nPosScreen)) %>%
  select(PATDEID, nPosScreens)
```

Comment: Please don't post images to share data, use `dput` instead. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using group_by() with summarize() and I have also tried rowSum() and mutate().

Comment: include what you have tried in your question using appropriate formatting. Never include vital information in a comment

Comment: Thank you for all the useful feedback on my post.

Answer (score 0):

Without have reproducible data, it looks like you want to stack the individual drug screenings using `pivot_longer()`. Then `group_by()` patient id and `summarise` to generate the sum within patient.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with('UDS'),
    names_to = 'drug',
    values_to = 'positive'
  ) %>%
  group_by(PATDEID) %>%
  summarise(
    nPosScreen = sum(positive, na.rm = T)
  ) %>%
  select(PATDEID, nPosScreen)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, I am getting errors when trying to use pivot_longer() function. It is not being recognized and I have tried installing the required packages but I am still getting errors.

Comment: `pivot_longer()` requires `tidyr 1.0.0`, but  you could try replacing this segment of the code with the deprecated `gather()` instead: gather(-PATDEID,-visit,key = 'drug',values = 'positive)

Answer (score 0):

if I get you correct, you just need to sum up for each patient, all non zero entries. So it's a matter of splitting the data frame (without the ID and week column), and doing a sum.

First I simulate some data that looks like yours:

```
#simulate data
set.seed(100)
PATIENTS = paste("ID",1:10,sep="")
VISITS = paste("wk",1:12,sep="")
COLS = paste("UDS",sprintf("%03d",5:14),sep="")
N=length(PATIENTS)*length(VISITS)*length(COLS)
Clean_urine_df = data.frame(
ID = rep(PATIENTS,each=length(VISITS)),
matrix(as.numeric(runif(N)>0.5),ncol=length(COLS)),
VISITS = rep(VISITS,each=length(PATIENTS))
)

colnames(Clean_urine_df)[2:11] = COLS
head(Clean_urine_df)

> head(Clean_urine_df)
   ID UDS005 UDS006 UDS007 UDS008 UDS009 UDS010 UDS011 UDS012 UDS013 UDS014
1 ID1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      1
2 ID1      0      0      1      0      0      1      0      1      0      1
3 ID1      1      0      1      1      1      0      1      1      1      0
4 ID1      0      1      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
5 ID1      0      0      0      1      0      0      1      0      1      1
6 ID1      0      0      1      1      0      1      0      1      1      0
  VISITS
1    wk1
2    wk1
3    wk1
4    wk1
5    wk1
6    wk1
```

Although I have already defined the columns I want to sum up, imagine in your scenario, you can define it again:

```
COLS <- c("UDS005","UDS006","UDS007","UDS008","UDS009","UDS010","UDS011","UDS012","UDS013", "UDS014")
```

Now as mentioned before, you can sum up using base R function:

```
counts = by(Clean_urine_df[,COLS],Clean_urine_df$ID,sum,simplify=TRUE)
data.frame(id=levels(Clean_urine_df$ID),nPosScreens=as.numeric(counts))
     id nPosScreens
1   ID1          61
2  ID10          57
3   ID2          56
4   ID3          65
5   ID4          60
6   ID5          61
7   ID6          61
8   ID7          64
9   ID8          67
10  ID9          65
```

the "by" function takes a matrix or data.frame, cuts it up according to Clean_urine_df$ID and sums everything up.

Likewise you can doing something in dplyr, but you need purrr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

t(map_df(split(Clean_urine_df[,COLS],Clean_urine_df$ID),sum))
```